# Excel VBA : Changing button click event into cell value change event

Tags: vba, excel, events

I created a simple value sum example driven by button click event as below.

```
Sub buttonEvent()

  Dim a As Double
  a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:A10"))
  Cells(11, 1).Value2 = a

End Sub
```

GUI is like below.

[image]

When I click sum button, this macro sums values in defined range.

I would like to change the click event as range value change event.

It means, as soon as I change a value in the range, value sum function will be performed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these codes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim a As Double
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
         a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:A10"))
             Cells(11, 1).Value2 = a
    End If
End Sub
```

`Edited after comment`
**For your clarification:**
[image]

Comment: I have a question. Must I change the macro name as Worksheet_Change?

Comment: No. You have to use code in `Worksheet_Change` event. It is not a macro name. It is built in sheet event.

Comment: I am afraid I am a beginner of VBA. How could I make the Worksheet_Change event?

Comment: See the screenshot. I hope it will clear answer now to you. Let me know if you still need clarification.

Comment: Double click on `Sheet1` in left side pane. Select `Worksheet` from above dropdown. Then select `Change` from right dropdown. Now copy paste above codes.

Comment: I got it~ Thank you very much for your detail explanation!